# put checkboxes next to items in table html php

Tags: php, html, checkbox

I have a webpage that allows users to view the log files on  the SD card that's on my Beaglebone. On this webpage, is a table with hyperlinks to the log files so that when the user  wants to view them, they click on the specific log file and it downloads to their local system. Now, I want to put checkboxes next to these items in my HTML table so that the user can delete them off the beaglebone server when they want  to.

The code was working perfectly before I tried to put the table into  a  form for the checkboxes. It showed up like  this:
[image: Before adding the form to delete]

But after adding the form, nothing shows up.
The file `unlink.php` refers to the code that deletes the files.
Here's the code:

```
<?php

$url = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];

$path = "/var/www/html/Logs";
$dh = opendir($path);

$k=0;
$foo=True;

while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false) {
    if($file != "." && $file != "..") {
    #echo "<a href='Logs/$file'>$file</a>";
    if($k==0 || $k %7==0){
        $col .= "<tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="file[]" value="Logs/$file"><a href='Logs/$file'>$file</a><br /></td>";
    }
    else if($k %7==6){
        $col .= "<td><input type="checkbox" name="file[]" value="Logs/$file"><a href='Logs/$file'>$file</a><br /></td></tr>"; 
    }
    else{
        $col .= "<td><input type="checkbox" name="file[]" value="Logs/$file"><a href='Logs/$file'>$file</a><br /></td>";
    }

    $k++;

}

}
echo "<form action="unlink.php" method="get"><table>$col</table><input type="submit" name="formSubmit" value="Submit" /></form> ";

closedir($dh);
?>
```

Comment: the inputs are outside the form for one thing

Comment: Are you getting errors? Your `echo` statement is using `"` but has unescaped `"` in it also so I would have thought it would be breaking the string

Comment: @Fred-ii- How are the inputs outside the form? They're all in $col, and $col is only called at the very end in the echo statement.

Comment: @avelampudi my mistake. The real issue here is parse errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line where you echo out the form tag and table, you need to either escape all the double quotes in your string or change them all to single quotes. You have strings like `"<form method="get">..."` and are using double quotes within double quotes which will cause an error. It should be something more like:

```
echo "<form action='unlink.php' method='get'><table>$col</table><input type='submit' name='formSubmit' value='Submit' /></form> ";
```

If you viewed the error log that php writes to, you would see this error.

Comment: I tried this,  it doesn't help. Where does php write the errors to?

Comment: You also need to escape/change the quotes on all the values getting added to $col

Comment: You also have same issue on all the lines with the checkboxes. Look at the syntax highlighting in your post. See how the colors change from red (string) to black/teal? That is because those are not part of a string.

Comment: OH, I did not realize double quotes  could cause an error

Comment: Well, since you are using double quotes for your string, when you hit another double quote in the string php thinks your string has ended. This could mean you plan on concatenating with another string or variable or it is just the end of the string/line.