# Deleting a file(s) from server PHP - Permission denied unlink

Tags: php, html, server, unlink

I want to delete files from my local server that's running on my beaglebone.

I have created a page that displays all the files and lets you select the files to delete. (As you can see below)

[image]

The webpage returns the names of the files  to delete in the form of an array to the php script unlink.php

The code for Unlink.php is:

```html
<?php

$files = $_POST['file'];

print_r($files);

if (empty($files)) {
    echo "No files were selected. Go back to 192.168.7.2 and refresh the page." ;
} else {
    $N = count($files);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $N; $i++) {
        $path = '/Logs/';
        print_r($path);
        #chown($path, 666);
        if (unlink($path . $_GET['$files[$i]'])) {
            echo ": Deleted";
        } else {
            echo "fail";
        }
    }
}
?>
```

However, whenever I try to delete a file: It fails.

The unlink() php function isn't being implemented properly and I'm not sure why.
How do I do this the right way?

The `index.html` page is located in `/var/www/html` and the logs are located in `/var/www/html/Logs/`. The address of the  local  server is `192.168.7.2`

Form code:

```html
<?php

$url = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
$path = "/var/www/html/Logs";
$dh = opendir($path);
$k = 0;
$foo = True;

while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false) {
    
    if ($file != "." && $file != "..") {
        
        if ($k == 0 || $k % 6 == 0) {
            $col .= "<tr><td><input type='checkbox' name='file[]' value='$file'>  <a href='Logs/$file'>$file</a><br /></td>";
        } else if ($k % 6 == 5) {
            $col .= "<td><input type='checkbox' name='file[]' value='$file'>  <a href='Logs/$file'>$file</a><br /></td></tr>";
        } else {
            $col .= "<td><input type='checkbox' name='file[]' value='$file'>  <a href='Logs/$file'>$file</a><br /></td>";
        }

        $k++;
    }
}
echo "<form action='unlink.php' method='post'><table>$col</table><br/><center><input type='submit' name='formSubmit' value='Delete' /></center></form>";

closedir($dh);
?>
```

EDIT: PHP display-errors

Warning: chmod(): Operation not permitted in /var/www/html/unlink.php on line 17 
 `chmod($path . $files[$i], 0755);`

Warning: unlink(/var/www/html/Logs/2017.01.24--13.43.43--0.log): Permission denied in /var/www/html/unlink.php on line 18 fail
 `if (unlink($path . $files[$i]))`

but when I check `ls -la` for /Logs -> it shows up as it belongs to `www-data`. How do I change the permissions beyond this?

Permissions:
[image]

Comment: `chown($path,666)` makes no sense. Unless if course you really do have a user named "666"

Comment: Sorry, that was an old part of the code - I was trying to see if that was the issue when I had the entire filepath in $path, but I've changed that since.

Comment: Your issue is probably `$_GET['$files[$i]']`. Just a guess, depending on the rest of your code, that it should be something like `$_GET[$files[$i]['name']]` (remove the single quotes around the `$files[]`, and add the actual file name.)

Comment: You are using both $_POST and $_GET, it's odd.. Can you share a bit of your form code ?

Comment: `$files = $_POST['file'];` that should more likely be `$files = $_FILES['file'];` (I could be wrong about that), but it's unsure as to the missing HTML form. In any case, check for errors with PHP's error reporting. IMHO, there isn't enough code to support the question and if they are treated as arrays.

Comment: I've included the form code now, I hope that  helps understand how the file names are being sent to unlink.php

Comment: You used `$path = "/var/www/html/Logs";` but then `$path='/Logs/';` so why not use the same path? could be a path issue. Again; error reporting would tell you if something's right or not. http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: (1) Your checkboxes are not inside your form tags. (2) Your form is `method='post'`, so you need to get rid of the `$_GET`.

Comment: @Sean *"Your checkboxes are not inside your form tags"* - I suggested that in their other question; they said it had nothing to do with that. http://stackoverflow.com/q/42076881/1415724

Comment: I stayed long enough; if anybody helped provide a solution; ping. I moved on, good luck sincerely.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I missed where they were building the rows in `$col` (not directly echoed) and then echoing `$col` in the form. Sometimes I read without really reading.

Comment: Maybe try `unlink($path . $files[$i])` ?

Comment: So the reason why I changed the path from /var/www/html/Logs is because the actual server doesn't access that. In my form code, as you can see, the hyperlinks which download the .log files are only called from 192.168.7.2/Logs/filename.log.

I changed the code to
`$path = '/var/html/www/Logs';`
`if(unlink($path.$files[$i])` instead of `_GET`

but still, it fails.

Comment: @Sean 'twas an honest mistake (that I made also). Hey, nobody's perfect...well, Jimmy Page maybe, but that's another story ♫~.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Haha, thank you though!

Comment: @avelampudi you're welcome. So... anything from `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); 
ini_set('display_errors', 1);` in your php? what about looking at the HTML source and var_dump'ing? there should be something that could help you find what's happening or not.

Comment: @avelampudi if you tried `$path = "/var/html/www/Logs/"; if (unlink($path.$files[$i]))` (note the trailing slash in the path) and it doesn't work then it may be a permissions issue (which changed using `chmod` not `chown` )

Comment: Permissions for the `/Logs` folder is already set to `www-data`
I'm clueless as to why it's not working, unless there's something wrong with the filepath

Comment: Checking out the PHP display-errors:

_Warning: chmod(): Operation not permitted in /var/www/html/unlink.php on line 17_ ::
`chmod($path . $files[$i], 0755);`

_Warning: unlink(/var/www/html/Logs/2017.01.24--13.43.43--0.log): Permission denied in /var/www/html/unlink.php on line 18 fail_ ::
`if (unlink($path . $files[$i]))`

but when I check ls -la for /Logs -> it shows up as it belongs to www-data. How do I change the permissions beyond this?

Comment: 1: Does the owner of the file have write permission?
2: Is the server process actually run by the user www-data?

Comment: @Rad80 I've included an image  of the permissions in the question if you want  to take a look. This is my first time working with  a web interface so I'm not exactly sure who  www-data is , but from what I've gathered from the web, it owns the web server.

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure the file that you are trying to pass to `unlink()` / delete is not being opened. If the file is `.exe` or etc please also check in *Windows Task Manager -> Process* and then kill it.
2. Change permission status of file. Maybe you can't have access to delete the file (execute permission).

After you sure the file is not being opened [1](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.chmod.php), then lets try this code :

```
// Check existence of file
if (file_exists($cekFile1)) {
    // make sure you have permission to delete file
    if(chmod($fileDir, 0777)){
        if(!unlink($cekFile1)){
            echo "unlink is fail !";
        }
    }else{
        echo "chmod is fail";
    }
    // owner have read, write, execute rights.
    // owner's user group only have read rights.
    // everybody else only have read rights.
    chmod($fileDir, 0744);

}
```

For more information about `chmod()`, please check this reference:

[php.net](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.chmod.php).

[php-cmod-function](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/php-chmod-function/).

Comment: nice reminded - unlink needs execute, I forgot and thought it would be write

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$files = $_POST['file'];
$path = "/var/www/html/Logs/";
print_r($files);

if (empty($files)) {
    echo "No files were selected. Go back to 192.168.7.2 and refresh the page." ;
} else {
    foreach ($files as $file) {
        if (unlink($path . $file)) {
            echo $path. $file ." : Deleted";
        } else {
            echo $path. $file . " : fail";
        }
    }
}
?>
```

That should do it, `$path` was wrong, and even if you had used the same as in the other code, it was missing a slash.
Nonetheless this code is not going to prevent malicious user actions.
[How to avoid UNLINK security risks in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3415418/how-to-avoid-unlink-security-risks-in-php)

From your updated question I can see that the Logs folder is a symlink to `/media/card/Logs`.
What is the output of `ls -la /media/card`?

Some further reads:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link
- http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Comment: I tried this code out and got the following errors:

Notice: Undefined index: $files[$i] in /var/www/html/unlink.php on line 21

Warning: unlink(/var/www/html/Logs/): Not a directory in /var/www/html/unlink.php on line 21